# What does it mean to "code against" or "resolve against" something?

Tags: java, oop, struts2, programming-languages, semantics

I've been reading a lot of computer science books and articles and I keep seeing the phrase "code against." For example, in the book *Struts 2 in Action* by Donald Brown, Chad Michael Davis, and Scott Stanlick, the following sentences can be found:

> - "Although it’s possible to write web applications by directly coding against the Servlet API, this is generally not considered a
>   good practice."
> - "This means that Java developers can write HTTP server code against an intuitive object-oriented abstraction of the HTTP client/server
>   communications."

In this book, particularly, there were a lot of instances of the use of the phrase "resolve against," as well. For example:

> - "When the framework invokes the result, your JSP page data access will
>   be resolved against the old object."
> - "The ValueStack represents the data model exposed to the current
>   request and is the default object against which all OGNL expressions
>   are resolved."
> - "If no namespace attribute is specified, then the action is resolved against the namespace of the current request."

I guess my confusion is based around the word "against." How and why is it used in this programming concept? I wouldn't think you'd want to code against something; rather, I'd think you'd want to code in correspondence with it. This could just be the author's phraseology, but can anyone help me out?

Comment: I believe that this is just, as you put it, the authors phraseology. When talking about using API's or libraries I wouldn't say coding against them but rather "using the API".

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Good question, but substantial overlap with, and possible duplicate of, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"against" is not used here as "in oposition" but rather as "supported by", "backed up by", "provided by",  "based on". One of the accepted meanings of the word "against" (Oxford dictionary) is

> In or into physical contact with (something), typically so as to be
>   supported by or collide with it

Of course, the "support" that the API (or whatever) gives you is not physical here :-)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know if the term "against" had any unique meaning or connotation in the programming context. As a result of all the abstraction involved in programming concepts, there are many English words that have very specific meanings within the programming world.